# Gnuplot smooth confidence band

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting

According to the answer given in this question [Gnuplot smooth confidence interval lines as opposed to error bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512006/gnuplot-smooth-confidence-interval-lines-as-opposed-to-error-bars/25512858?noredirect=1#comment48933581_25512858) I was able to get the same result for my data given by (the error of y is symmetric so it is y plus/minus errorY):

```
# x y errorY   
1   3   0.6 
2   5   0.4  
3   4   0.2
4   3.5 0.3
```

Code:

```
set style fill transparent solid 0.2 noborder
plot 'data.dat' using 1:($2-$3):($2+$3) with filledcurves title '95% confidence', \
     '' using 1:2 with lp lt 1 pt 7 ps 1.5 lw 3 title 'mean value'
```

Now the confidence band is given by connecting every y+errorY and y-errorY point. I would like it if the connection is not just a straight line, but rather a smooth line, like how one can smoothen data points with `smooth csplines`..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a bit tricky, because smoothing works only on a single column, and can't be directly combined with the `filledcurves` plotting style.

So you must first generate two temporary data files by plotting the smoothed upper and lower confidence boundaries to separate data files with

```
set table 'lower.dat'
plot 'data.dat' using 1:($2-$3) smooth cspline
set table 'upper.dat'
plot 'data.dat' using 1:($2+$3) smooth cspline
unset table
```

And then combining those two files with `paste lower.data upper.dat` before plotting the data. If you don't have the `paste` command line program, you can also use any other script like [`paste.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20070138/2604213) to merge the files:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'data.png'

set style fill transparent solid 0.2 noborder
plot '< paste lower.dat upper.dat' using 1:2:5 with filledcurves title '95% confidence', \
     'data.dat' using 1:2 with lines lt 1 smooth cspline title 'mean value',\
     '' using 1:2 with points lt 1 pt 7 ps 1.5 lw 3 title 'data points'
```

[image]